# Cannot set PopupMenuStyle if disable title and ActionBar, issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I want to set a Style for `PopupMenu` unfortunately I'm facing with a strange issue if I try to disable ActionBar and Title in Holo with

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<style>
```

same result if I use directly `Theme.NotitleBar`rather than Holo

All my popup menu appears in this way in devices with ICS or JellyBean

[image]

And I cannot change background and font colors using styles.xml

**EDIT**

I have noticed that this bug happens if I add the menu in this way

```
OnClickListener showMenu= new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getBaseContext(), v);
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.my_menu,
                popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                    ....

                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        /** Showing the popup menu */
        popup.show();
    }
};
```

But not if I don't use inflater and add manually only via code the menu entries.

How could I solve this problem? Is there any other solution?

Comment: Are you using actionbarsherlock ?

Comment: @gomino
no the standard android PopUpMenu

Comment: I have update the question to better understand the scenario that cause this strange issue

Comment: try changing the context from getBaseContext() to youractivity.this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mind you the popover is only available after target API 11 or more.
For easier usage, i always set targetsdkversion and project build target as the same and above 11 (though they need not strictly be the same).

targetsdkversion - manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

Project build target

```
Right click on the project -> properties -> android ->project build target (4.1)
```

Also, instead of editing res/values/styles.xml , try changing res/values-v11/styles.xml:

res/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        *Your style definitions for versions targeting < API version 11*
    </style>
</resources>
```

res/values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MainTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
     *your style definitions for the popup menu within versions 11-14*
     <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">...</item>
     <item name="android:popupAnimationStyle">...</item>
     <item name="android:popupBackground">...</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I have only styles.xml should I create themes.xml?

Comment: You have to edit styles.xml itself. I have edited my post to reflect the changes.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately doesn't works, see the update to my question

Answer (score 0):

I used the sample code [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/working-with-androids-popupmenu-class/2396) and changed the style. It only changed the background in main.xml not the PopupMenu, but I was test on simulator I am not sure that would make any difference.

Comment: the code is similar to the mine but the problem is that if I disable the action bar all popup menu seems ignoring the style

Comment: and I told you that didn't happen to me. did you have more than one style.xml

Comment: I have the standard styles.xml for different version in values-v11 and values-v14, I haven't created others styles.xml files. Have you tried to use  `<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`??